# IllegalStateException vs UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, illegalstateexception

I'm confusing of using exception: **IllegalStateException** vs **UnsupportedOperationException**.

I have a delete method which in some cases do not allow to use: let's say when the caller has a valid data on it.

Then I should give an exception info to user that he is doing an invalid operation now.

So, which exception should I throw? **IllegalStateException** or **UnsupportedOperationException**.

***I know I can give the detail message using any of them, but I still want to know which one is better in my case.***

**From JavaDoc:**

- **IllegalStateException:**

Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time. In other words, the Java environment or Java application is not in an appropriate state for the requested operation.

- **UnsupportedOperationException:**

Thrown to indicate that the requested operation is not supported.

Comment: This is primarily opinion-based. If you only throw exception in certain illegal states, I'd vot for `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: @lexicore Although a question asking for _when to use X and when to use Y_ seems to be opinion-based, there is a clear distinction between those two exceptions that can easily be explained objectively, I think.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`UnsupportedOperationException` should be used as the method is not supported **at all** while `IllegalStateException` should be used as the method is supported but that in the current state, it is not legal.

The `Iterator` classes are good candidates to illustrate the difference between these two exceptions.

[`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) implements `remove()` in a default method by throwing a `UnsupportedOperationException` :

```
public interface Iterator<E> {
    ...
    default void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("remove");
    }
    ...
}
```

The method is indeed never supported by implementations that don't override this method to support it.

About implementations, we can see that the `Iterator` implementation used by the [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) class overrides `remove()` to support it. So `UnsupportedOperationException` is not thrown any longer.

On the other hand, we can also see that the method  throws an `IllegalStateException` if you invoke it while you never invoked `next()` to make progress the iterator to the next element :

```
private class Itr implements Iterator<E> {
    ...
    public void remove() {      
        if (lastRet < 0)
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        checkForComodification();

        try {
            ArrayList.this.remove(lastRet);
            cursor = lastRet;
            lastRet = -1;
            expectedModCount = modCount;
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        }
    ...
    }
}
```

The method is so supported by this implementation but if you invoke it in a illegal state, an `IllegalStateException` is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

**IllegalStateException:**
This one is a little less common, but is useful a method relies on a previous method having been called.

For example, if your object requires its initialise() method to be called before other methods, then you can set a flag inside initialise(), and throw an IllegalStateException if initialise() hasn't been called:

```
private boolean initted;

public void initialise() {
  // ...
  initted = true;
}
public void doSomething() {
  if (!initted)
    throw new IllegalStateException("Object not initialised");
}
```

**UnsupportedOperationException:**
This exception is designed for cases where you override an abstract class or implement an interface, but don't want or can't to implement certain methods.

It is used by various classes of the Java Collections Framework. Ideally, your interface or method should also provide a means for the caller to determine in advance whether it expects the given operation to be supported.